# split exception: Chunk map pointed to incorrect chunk

Tags: mongodb

I am currently in the process of learning mongodb. I have a collection that is sharded on student_id key. While trying to execute split command with bounds on the sharded collection, I get the following exception "*exception: Chunk map pointed to incorrect chunk*"

```
mongos> db.runCommand( { split: "test.grades" , bounds: [ Object(0), Object(10) ] } )

{ "code" : 13141, "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "exception: Chunk map pointed to incorrect chunk" }
```

**Note:** I haven't loaded the data at this point, which means that no splits are already in place.

I am able to get this working by using the alternatives for bound such as:

```
db.runCommand( { split: "test.grades" , middle:{student_id:10000} } )
```

I am also aware about 'tag aware sharding' and how it can be used for this particular case. The only thing I am unable to fugure out is why split not working with 'bounds' option.

Any pointers will be appreciated!

Comment: [From docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/split/): 
"The values must match the minimum and maximum values of an existing chunk"
Also "bounds applies to chunks in collections partitioned using a hashed shard key"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

orid is correct. To split by bounds you have to use a hashed shard key, and you can only use it on the max and min values of existing chunks. In your case, the data is not present yet, so there are no existing chunks.

Also to use bounds, you would need to specify a key like this:

```
db.runCommand( { split: "test.grades" , bounds: [ {student_id: Object(0)}, {student_id: Object(10)} ] } )
```